# How to concat char* while loop? c++

Tags: c++, char

Basically i want to know how to concat char* during a for loop , and return a char* that is a concat of all those char* in the deque. Its important to return char*, **not** const char* **or** string.

i've tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    deque <char*> q;
    q.push_back("hello");
    q.push_back("world");
    char* answer = (char*)malloc(10);
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        strcat(answer, q.front());
        q.pop_front();
    }
    cout << answer<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the output is really "helloworld" as i want, but i get this:

```
main.cpp:12:23: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'std::deque<char*>::value_type {aka char*}' [-Wwrite-strings]                                         
q.push_back("world");
```

How can i get rid of this warning? every solution i found tells me to put "const" before char* but again, i have to return char*. tnx!

Comment: Try `deque <const char*> q;`

Comment: Why aren't you using `string`?

Comment: also - you are only allocating 10 bytes for `answer` with your malloc - hello + world = 10 characters, and `strcat` will add a null string terminator, so your code would be writing to 11 bytes.

Comment: Potentially because it's homework.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ,@barak manos, i wrote before - can't use them.

Comment: @user2637293 You can't use `const char*`?? That doesn't mean you need to use it for `answer`.

Comment: "answer" must be char*, nothing else.

Comment: If only `answer` must be `char*`, then you're allowed to store `const char*` in the `deque`.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the warnings and use `strcat()` properly, you should fix your code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    std::deque <const char*> q;
             // ^^^^^
    q.push_back("hello");
    q.push_back("world");
    char* answer = (char*)malloc(11);
                              // ^^ preserve enough space to hold the 
                              //    terminating `\0` character added
                              //    by strcat()
    answer[0] = 0; // << set the initial '\0' character
    while (!q.empty()) {
        strcat(answer, q.front());
        q.pop_front();
    }
    std::cout << answer<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`answer` can stay declared as `char*` as you requested in your question.